# Firebase nodemailer - problem with snapshot data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I want recieve email with variable "mail" "message" "name" .... Like "Hello {name} how are you ? your email are {mail} and here is a copy of your {message} from contact form" ..... And problem is i just recieving {mail} and not {message} {name}

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.login;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.pass;

admin.initializeApp();


var goMail = function (message) {


    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: gmailEmail,
            pass: gmailPassword
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: gmailEmail, 
        to: 'la***@gmail.com', 
        subject: 'Hello ✔', 
        text: '!' + message, 
        html: '!' + message 
    };

    const getDeliveryStatus = function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);

    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, getDeliveryStatus);
}; 
exports.onDataAdded = functions.database.ref('/emails/{sessionId}').onCreate(function (snap, context) {

    const createdData = snap.val();
    var text = createdData.mail;
        goMail(text);
});
```

And this is how looks my firebase Realtime DB

```
 emails
     -**sesionID*
        mail: "randommail@gmail.com"
        message:"test"
        name:"testname"
```

I try it ADD/EDIT this from code up, but this not help :-/

```
   var goMail = function (message, secondmessage)


   const mailOptions = {
        from: gmailEmail, 
        to: 'la***@gmail.com', 
        subject: 'Hello ✔', 
        text: '!' + message +  secondmessage, 
        html: '!' + message +  secondmessage
    };


 var text = createdData.mail;
 var secondtext = createdData.name
 goMail(text, secondtext);
```

Thanks you everyone for answer and have nice day !

Comment: Hello Radek, welcome to Stack Overflow, I did not understood very well what is happening on your code, do you get any error message or are the results just not what you expected? can you edit the question with the error message or what results are you expecting/what you are getting? Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see more information about what you should add to a question. Also, I noticed in your code that you are calling your gomail function with 2 parameter, even though only 1 is expected, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks Ralemos, thanks for a link i will be next time better :-) . I did not recive result what i expected... I want recieve email with variable "mail" "message" "name" .... Like  "Hello {name} how are you ? your email are {mail} and here is a copy of your {message} from contact form"  ..... And problem is i just recieving {mail} and not {message} {name}

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving only {{mail}} because that value is already set as a constant value on you cloud function, also on the call of your goMail function by your code, you are sending 2 parameters instead of the 1 parameter expected. try changing your goMail function to (as an example):

```
var goMail = function (name, message) {


    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: gmailEmail,
            pass: gmailPassword
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: gmailEmail, 
        to: 'la***@gmail.com', 
        subject: 'Hello ✔', 
        text: '!' + name + message, 
        html: '!' + name + message 
    };

    const getDeliveryStatus = function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);

    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, getDeliveryStatus);
};
```

and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks again Ralemos... i try it and receive email with " !undefinedundefined" :(

Comment: Ok, we are getting somewhere, you are using this call, right? `goMail(text, secondtext);`. if you are, this means that `createdData.mail` and `createdData.name` is returning undefined, and that is what you must check, try to log your `createdData` object to see what it shows.

Comment: Here is a console.log(createdData);  onDataAdded
{ email: 'spider@avenger.com', loading: false, message: 'tsss spider silk .....', name: 'Petr Parker' }               and  i see one error in console "onDataAdded
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"

Comment: I believe the problem is that your call of `gomail()` call inside the `onDataAdded` function still only uses one parameter, change it to `goMail(text,createdData.name)` (this is an example, not sure what the logic you trying to make is). Try it out and let me know if this is it.